# Laurent series for $\frac{1}{z+1}+\frac{1}{z-3}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, laurent-series

Find the Laurent series expansion for

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z+1}+\frac{1}{z-3},$$

in the domains

(a) $0<\vert z \vert <1$,

(b) $1<\vert z \vert<3$,

and

(c) $3<\vert z \vert<\infty.$

**Attempt:**

(a) We have

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z+1}+\frac{1}{z-3}&=\frac{1}{1+z}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{3}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nz^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{3^{n+1}}.
\end{align}

For (b) I get

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z+1}+\frac{1}{z-3}&=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z}}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{3}}\\
&=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\bigg(\frac{1}{z}\bigg)^n-\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{z}{3}\bigg)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty} (-1)^{n+1}z^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{3^{n+1}}.
\end{align}

For (c) I have

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z+1}+\frac{1}{z-3}&=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z}}+\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{z}}\\
&=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{z}\bigg)^n+\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{3}{z}\bigg)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty}z^n+\sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty}\frac{z^n}{3^{n+1}}.
\end{align}

Am I correct? Thanks for any tips or hints if I am incorrect anywhere. Ill take an upvote as in, I am doing things correctly..

Comment: All of it looks good.

Comment: Thanks @Integralfan !!

Comment: I have not checked, but you did the right things